# Conditional Probability World Problem which is easy for you but difficult for me :)

Tags: probability

A professor has taught probability and statis-
tics for many years and he found the following results:
80 percent of students who do the homework, pass the exam. 10 percent of students who
don’t do the homework, pass the exam. If 60 percent of the students do the homework,
what percent of the students pass the exam? From students who pass the exam, what
percent did the homework?

Comment: You probably meant "word problem".

Comment: Try it with numbers.  Suppose there are $100$ students exactly.  How many of those did the homework? how many of the homework-doing students passed?  Same for the non-homework-doing students.

Comment: Yeah I have tried but couldn't do so. Because I am very weak in probability 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the $60\%$ who did the homework $80\%$ will pass. This accounts for $48\%$ of the students. From the remaining $40\%$ only $10\%$ will pass which is $4\%$. 
So $52\%$ of the students will pass. The fraction of the students that did the homework equals $\frac{48}{48+4}$, which equals approximately $92\%$

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have got my answer. You are really awesome 

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean that "How many percent of the students in total passed the exam and did the somework?", because if the problem states exactly like that, the answer is obviously $80$%.

**HINT:**

Let $x$ be the number of students in total ($x$ will help you make expressions easier to find the solution, but you don't have to find $x$).

Based on the question, $0.6x$ students did the homework, $0.4x$ of students didn't do their homework.

$80$% of the $0.6x$ students who did the homework passed their exam.

$10$% of the $0.4x$ students who didn't do the somework passed their exam.

Simply calculate the number of students who passed their exam AND did the homework (in terms of $x$), you will get the desired result.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have done my question. You gave me an excellent and explained hint. Thank you very much sir!

Comment: @TechnicalGen. You're welcome, you can upvote this answer as a way to say thanks